# Discord.js - Get last user that left a voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get the last user that left a voice channel.

I've found the `client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState)=>{})` event that allows me to detect when a member leaves or joins the VC. However, I cannot find a way to determine which guild member has joined/left. I know that I can get the channel from oldState.channel, but I can't get the user who left in any way. I'd like to avoid managing a global state of all users in VC, is there any way to do this via event-driven logic alone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate), the `oldState` and `newState` objects are both [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceState) objects. `VoiceState` has the property `.id`, which you can use to identify the user who has left or joined. There seems to also be the field `.member`, which has more data. I'm unsure which would be preferable in this context.

Comment: I had missed that this ID was linked to a member, thanks